# Detect five consecutive unsorted integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers

It appears that the product of the differences between 3 consecutive integers in whatever order is always equal to 2. However, I can't find the pattern for 5 integers.

We could sort them and get an easier problem, but I am curious if there is a way to solve it on an unsorted 5 integers array.

Edit: Gentlemen in comments pointed out it works for non sorted 3 integers. Question remains. Is there such a property for 5 integers ?

Edit:

The product of $|a-b|$ and $|b-c|$ is always 2.

let an integers array x be $3, 1, 2$

we have : $ (|3 - 1|) \cdot (|1 - 2|)$ = 2

Is there such a relation with 5 integers ?

Comment: How do you define "product of differences"? Which is the product of differences of $(1,2,3)$: $(2-1)(3-2)$ or $(2-1)(3-2)(3-1)$? I guess it's $(2-1)(3-2)(3-1)$ since the other product is $1$, not $2$, but this is unclear in the question. It's also unclear how you intend to extend the definition to more than three consecutive integers.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the product always being $2$.  Are you taking all differences or just some of them?

Comment: If you take the entire set of pairwise differences (without duplication), you would get $4!\cdot 3!\cdot 2!\cdot 1!$...

Comment: Here's what I think you mean: "give three integers $a,b,c$, we know that these integers can be sorted into a consecutive sequence if and only if $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=2$. I would like to know if a similar result applies to larger sets of integers". Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom sorry if it wasn't clear, added details

Comment: I do not believe that your statement is true.  If you have the integers $1$, $2$, and $3$ (in that order), then, $|1-2|\cdot|2-3|=1\cdot 1=1$, which is not $2$.

Comment: Well it appears I was wrong then.

Comment: If you look at all differences (not just consecutive differences), you will get a pattern, however.

Comment: It works for 3 if you require them to be unsorted.   Clearly if the differences are all one or -1 its easy to "sort" them.   Let a= 7, b=9, c = 8 then |b-a| = 2, |c-b| = 1.  $2\cdot{1} = 2$.

Comment: Very interesting I didn't realize it doesn't work if they were sorted. Is there such a property for 5 integers ?

Answer (score 1):

Take any $5$ numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ and multiply the absolute differences differences between consecutive numbers. You get
$$
|a-b|\cdot|b-c|\cdot|c-d|\cdot|d-e|
$$

if you imagine to add to each of the five numbers the same constant, it is easy to see that this product does not change, because each difference remain the same.

So, if I'm considering $5$ numbers it does not matter if they are $1,2,3,4,5$ or $14,15,16,17,18$, because the product of the differences among adiacent numbers will remain the same.

Clearly, if we take the $5$ consecutive numbers in their natural order, or in reverse order, the product will be a product of $1$'s, and thus equal to $1$.

But there are $5!=120$ ways to permute $5$ numbers and it turns out that we can have $13$ different products, namely $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $6$, $8$, $9$, $12$, $16$, $18$, $24$, $36$, $48$, depending on how we permute them.

Here is a table of the $13$ values, the number of corresponding permutations, and one such permutation.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\prod & \sharp & perm.\\\hline
 1 & 2 & 12345 \\
 2 & 4 & 12354 \\
 3 & 4 & 12543 \\
 4 & 18 & 12435 \\
 6 & 20 & 12534 \\
 8 & 12 & 13542 \\
 9 & 6 & 14325 \\
 12 & 8 & 13425 \\
 16 & 12 & 15324 \\
 18 & 8 & 14352 \\
 24 & 12 & 13524 \\
 36 & 10 & 14253 \\
 48 & 4 & 24153
\end{array}
$$

For example, the line that start with $18$ means that it is possible to obtain the product $18$ with $8$ permutations, one being $14352$, which means we take the first number, then the $4$th, then the $3$rd, the $5$th and the second.

For example, for the numbers $18,19,20,21,22$ this means the order 
$18,21,20,22,19$ which indeed gives
$$
|18-21|\cdot|21-20|\cdot|20-22|\cdot|22-19|=3\cdot1\cdot2\cdot3 = 18
$$

The number $T$ of different values and the maximal product $M$ that it is possible to obtain with $k$ consecutive numbers can be summarized as follows, for $k=2,\dots,10$.
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
k&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\\hline
T&1& 2 & 6 & 13 & 42 & 92 & 292 & 653 & 1345\\\hline
M& 1 & 2 & 12 & 48 & 432 & 2700 & 32000 & 276480 & 4050000
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You proposition works for a sequence of 3 numbers if you only look at unsorted sequences. WLOG we can use {1} {2} and {3} to illustrate.

123 = sorted ascending

321 = sorted descending

132 = |3-1| x |2-3| = 2

312 = |1-3| x |2-1| = 2

213 = |1-2| x |3-1| = 2

231 = |3-2| x |1-3| = 2

There is no similar property for a sequence of 5 numbers.

12354 = 1x1x2x1=2

12435 = 1x2x1x2=4

15243 = 4x3x2x1=24

etc...

Comment: But 123 and 321 => 1 $\ne $ 2 so if that's what the op meant.

Answer (score -1):

Is this a serious question?

If $a < b <c < d <e$ are 5 consecutive integers then:

e - a =4

e-b= 3

e-c=2

e-d =1

d-a=3

d-b =2

d-c=1

c-a =2

b-a =1

The product is 4x3x2x1x3x2x1x2x1=288.

Was that a serious question?

Comment: Yes. Serious question. "I am curious if there is a way to solve it on an unsorted 5 integers array." 5 unsorted integers

Comment: What does "sorted" mean?  What difference would the order make.  If they are consecutive the largest, whichever one it is, is 4 away from the smallest, there are two that are three appart, three that are two apart, and for that are 1 apart.  So of course the answer is always going to be the same and very easy to figure out.

Comment: there are only 4 differences between five elements in a sequence,  The question did not say to multiply all differences

Comment: The question didn't say anything about which differences to multiply.  Obviously if you multiply different differences you get a different result.